# Possibly link PC to Landline Telephone through href="tel"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-applications, href, telephony

I want to connect my web application to a real live telephone by using the "tel:xxxxx" href attribute in HTML. I cannot make it go through skype or anything because internet is more expensive here. I want it to go through direct landline. As in when the user clicks the link; the phone would automatically dial said number.

What hardware and software do I need?

What do I need to do in order to get started?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not be able to directly do this from a browser application, because you will need interface to hardware on your PC:

[http://www.amazon.com/Robotics-USB-Dial-Up-Softmodem-USR5639/dp/B009019KR4/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1451365015&sr=8-1&keywords=dial+up+usb+modem](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B009019KR4)

You can either build a native PC app using ruby (or any other language), or if you want to deploy from your browser you can use the loco-ruby (https://github.com/catmando/LocoRuby) application that will provide a browser to PC interface.

The modem hardware will come with probably enough information on how to actually dial the phone etc.